# How to paginate a request asyncronously in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to extract the data from a response, which contains a cursor token that when passed as a parameter to the request url, returns the next 100 results. The cursor token is a hash value. I have figured out how to paginate one result, but I can not figure out how to paginate and result all of the results.

written synchronously, working code looks like this:

```
s = requests.Session()

def get_paginated_data(link):

    responses=[]

    req = s.get(link).json()
    if req['data']:
        responses.append(req)

    while 'cursor' in req:
        req = s.get(link, params={'cursor':req['cursor']})
        if req['data']:
            responses.append(req)

    return responses

data = [get_paginated_data(link) for link in links]
```

I have tried this so far, but it only returns one paginated result. I was trying to mimick what was being done [here](https://dev.to/hughrawlinson/handling-pagination-with-async-iterators-1p4f).

```
s = requests.Session()

async def makeRequest(endpoint, params=None):

  req = s.get(endpoint).json()
  yield req
  if 'cursor' in req:
    yield s.get(endpoint, params={'cursor':req['cursor']}).json()


async def loads(endpoint):

  responses=[]

  req= [i async for i in makeRequest(endpoint)]

  if req['data']:
    responses.append(req['data'])

  return responses 

  # using a while loop like in the synchronous code does not work and result in an infinite loop.
```

Comment: The biggest difference to me is that your synchronous version uses a while loop and your synchronous version uses an if.